# How to make dynamic pivot with date and another column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
 NAME          VALUE       IDENTIFIER          MYDATE
NAME1           123           ATR            01/10/2018  
NAME1           333           QTDE           01/10/2018  
NAME2           212           ATR            01/08/2018  
NAME2           123           QTDE           01/08/2018 
NAME2           133           ATR            01/09/2018  
NAME2           123           QTDE           01/09/2018  
NAME3           678           ATR            01/08/2018  
NAME3           123           QTDE           01/08/2018
```

In `IDENTIFIER`, it will be only `ATR` or `QTDE`.
I need to make a pivot to get the `VALUE` of `QTDE` or `ATR` of every month so the result will be something like

```
NAME        QTDE08/2018        ATR08/2018        QTDE09/2018        ATR09/2018        QTDE10/2018        ATR10/2018
NAME1           0                   0               0                   0                 333                123
NAME2          123                 212             123                 133                 0                  0
NAME3          123                 678              0                   0                  0                  0
```

I have tried to make the pivot, but I could only do with `IDENTIFIER` and I have no clue how to make it with the date as well

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ST.NAME,
               ST.VALUE,
               ST.IDENTIFIER,
               TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ST.MYDATE), 'MM/YYYY') AS MYDATE
          FROM SOME_TABLE ST
         WHERE ST.IDENTIFIER IN ('QTDE', 'ATR')) 
PIVOT(SUM(VALUE)
      FOR IDENTIFIER IN ('QTDE' AS QTDE,
                         'ATR' AS ATR))
```

I edit the table and colunms name, it's not the original one from my table.

Comment: You can't. It seems you want the dates (or at least their `'MM/YYYY'` representation) to come from the data, not be hard-coded into the query in advance. This is called "dynamic pivoting", it can be done - but not in plain SQL, and it is generally a poor practice. WHY do you need the output in that format? If it's just for reporting, you may be better off using a reporting application that has the capability to do such dynamic pivoting in the application.

Comment: @mathguy you said `You can't` and after `This is called "dynamic pivoting", it can be done`. I don't understand. And also, yes, it's for reporting.

Comment: "You can't" as in, "you can't in the way you are asking" - that is, in a standard `SELECT` query. "It can be done" but "*you* can't do it" (I doubt that you can, anyway.) Does that make sense?

Comment: It can't be done in SQL but i can be done in the reporting application? By the way, I'm using telerik

Comment: I am not familiar with telerik (and really with reporting applications in general); I believe their code is usually proprietary, but it is not hard to guess that they probably use dynamic SQL under the hood. The point being, it is much easier to learn how to "do" the dynamic pivoting by using application features, than it is to learn dynamic SQL and write the code yourself, from scratch. Find out what pivoting capabilities telerik may have.

Comment: Just so you understand: the issue with dynamic pivoting is that "straight" SQL requires the number of output columns to be known in advance, it can't be dynamic. (Actually the number of columns, their names, their data types and their order - column order - must all be known when you write the query, not after the runtime engine inspects the data.)

Comment: Even if it's harder, I would prefer to learn how to do `dynamic SQL and write the code yourself`. I understand your point, but I'm still waiting for how to do this in `dynamic SQL`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191618/discussion-between-vencovsky-and-mathguy).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert 2 columns date and identifier so you need 2 pivots.
Please try below query, it should work. Don't hesitate to come back in case of any queries. This works in oracle but not sure if you are trying in any other dbms.

```
select * from (
select * from (
with all_data as 
(select 'NAME1' fname, 123 value, 'ATR' identif, '01-OCT-2018' mydate from dual union all
select 'NAME1' fname, 333 value, 'QTDE' identif, '01-OCT-2018'  mydate from dual union all
select 'NAME2' fname, 212 value, 'ATR' identif, '01-AUG-2018'  mydate from dual union all
select 'NAME2' fname, 123 value, 'QTDE' identif, '01-AUG-2018'  mydate from dual union all
select 'NAME2' fname, 133 value, 'ATR' identif, '01-SEP-2018'  mydate from dual union all
select 'NAME2' fname, 123 value, 'QTDE' identif, '01-SEP-2018'  mydate from dual union all
select 'NAME3' fname, 678 value, 'ATR' identif, '01-AUG-2018'  mydate from dual union all
select 'NAME3' fname, 123 value, 'QTDE' identif, '01-AUG-2018'  mydate from dual )
select identif,fname,value,mydate from  all_data)
pivot 
(
sum(value)
for mydate in ('01-AUG-2018' as "AUG-2018",'01-SEP-2018' as "SEP-2018",'01-OCT-2018' as "OCT-2018")))
pivot
(
sum("AUG-2018") "08-2018"
,sum("SEP-2018") "09-2018"
,sum("OCT-2018") "10-2018"
for identif in ('ATR' ATR,'QTDE' QTDE))
order by 1;
```

Comment: with your answer, I would need to list all days and all years to make it work, and every month I would need to add new lines to the code to cover all years. That's not the answer to this problem, I can't make thousands of line to cover all possible dates

Comment: Please use the dynamic sql to input dates and identify values.

Comment: How to use the dynamic sql? I have no ideia, please explain @sudheer

Answer (score 0):

below example needs to be rewritten in Oracle and specific to ur requirement.

```
CREATE TABLE Project(PRJ_ID int, UDN_ID INT, TXT_VALUE varchar(100));

INSERT INTO Project VALUES (8344,82,'E S'),(8344,69,'A M'),(8364,82,'End'),(8364,59,'Internal');

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @columns1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

--selecting distinct values and concatenating to get a result like [82],[69],[82]...


SELECT @columns1 = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + '['+ CAST(UDN_ID AS VARCHAR) + ']' FROM Project
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM Project;


--using that dynamic column string in the pivot query string


SET @sql = 'SELECT PRJ_ID,' + @columns1 + ' FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM Project
) AS src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(TXT_VALUE) FOR src.UDN_ID IN ('+ @columns1
  + ')
) AS p;';


--executing the pivot query


EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This answer have nothing to do with the question, please make and example that is related to the question