# How to make pivot have default value in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

This question can be related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612937/using-pivot-on-identifier-and-date-on-oracle).

I have a query that makes a pivot on `QTDE` and `ATR` but also on the date, so I made the following

```
SELECT      *
FROM (
    SELECT  ...
            GPC.EVENT_VALUE,
            GPC.IDENTIFIER,
            TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(GPC.SCHEDULE_DATE), 'MM') AS SCHEDULE_DATE
    FROM    GP_CALCULATION GPC
    WHERE   RO_CODE = 'MQ'
    AND     GPC.IDENTIFIER IN ('QTDE', 'ATR')
) 
PIVOT(   
    SUM(EVENT_VALUE)
    FOR (IDENTIFIER, SCHEDULE_DATE)
    IN (
        ('QTDE', '01') AS QTDE01,
        ('ATR', '01') AS ATR01,
        ('QTDE', '02') AS QTDE02,
        ('ATR', '02') AS ATR02,
        ('QTDE', '03') AS QTDE03,
        ('ATR', '03') AS ATR03,
        ('QTDE', '04') AS QTDE04,
        ('ATR', '04') AS ATR04,
        ('QTDE', '05') AS QTDE05,
        ('ATR', '05') AS ATR05,
        ('QTDE', '06') AS QTDE06,
        ('ATR', '06') AS ATR06,
        ('QTDE', '07') AS QTDE07,
        ('ATR', '07') AS ATR07,
        ('QTDE', '08') AS QTDE08,
        ('ATR', '08') AS ATR08,
        ('QTDE', '09') AS QTDE09,
        ('ATR', '09') AS ATR09,
        ('QTDE', '10') AS QTDE10,
        ('ATR', '10') AS ATR10,
        ('QTDE', '11') AS QTDE11,
        ('ATR', '11') AS ATR11,
        ('QTDE', '12') AS QTDE12,
        ('ATR', '12') AS ATR12
    )
)
```

## The Problem

When there is no match on the pivot, it comes like this

[image: query]

I'm using PL/SQL Developer to see the results, and I'm getting this "blank" that I don't know what is. Is that equals to `''` ?

How can I make values that are "blank" become `0`?

Comment: I removed the `plsql` tag, because there is no PL/SQL in your question (only plain SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the only PL/SQL part is that i'm using PL/SQL developer to query, but it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that for this identifier / month there was no data in your table (or there were only null values). If you want to see `0` use `case` or `nvl` in `select` part, like in ths example:

```
-- sample data 
with gp_calculation(event_value, identifier, schedule_date, ro_code) as (
    select 12, 'QTDE', date '2018-12-24', 'MQ' from dual union all
    select  7, 'QTDE', date '2018-12-24', 'MQ' from dual union all
    select 42, 'ATR',  date '2018-11-24', 'MQ' from dual union all
    select 13, 'QTDE', date '2018-11-24', 'MQ' from dual union all
    select 17, 'QTDE', date '2018-11-24', 'MQ' from dual )
-- end of data

select nvl(q10, 0) qtde10, nvl(a10, 0) atr10, 
       nvl(q11, 0) qtde11, nvl(a11, 0) atr11, 
       nvl(q12, 0) qtde12, nvl(a12, 0) atr12
  from (select  gpc.event_value, gpc.identifier,
                to_char(to_date(gpc.schedule_date), 'MM') as schedule_date
          from  gp_calculation gpc
          where ro_code = 'MQ'
            and gpc.identifier in ('QTDE', 'ATR')) 
  pivot(sum(event_value) for (identifier, schedule_date) in (
                               ('QTDE', '10') as q10, ('ATR', '10') as a10,
                               ('QTDE', '11') as q11, ('ATR', '11') as a11,
                               ('QTDE', '12') as q12, ('ATR', '12') as a12 ))
```

Result:

```
    QTDE10      ATR10     QTDE11      ATR11     QTDE12      ATR12
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         0          0         30         42         19          0
```